# GMapsFX displaying a blank map

Tags: google-maps, javafx

I'm having two error messages:

```
ERROR com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView - Error: User data directory [null (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\application.Main\webview)] is already in use
```

and

```
INFO com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView - Alert: Hide directions called
```

I'm using JAVAFX11 Library on Eclipse, I've edit my run configuration to add javafx.web module.
I think that the problem occurs when I create a GoogleMapView object but I'dont know how to resolve! Thanks in advice to anyone who can help me.

This is my controller class:

```
package controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.MapComponentInitializedListener;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.GoogleMap;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.LatLong;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapTypeIdEnum;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.service.geocoding.GeocodingService;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class GMaps_Controller implements Initializable, MapComponentInitializedListener{

@FXML
private GoogleMapView gmapView;

@FXML
private TextField nomeField;

@FXML
private TextField capField;

@FXML
private TextField addressField;

@FXML
private Button findAddress;

@FXML
private Button findCap;

@FXML
private Button findNome;

private GoogleMap map;

private GeocodingService geocodingService;

private StringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty();

@FXML
void findAddressPushed(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void findCapPushed(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void findNomePushed(ActionEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    gmapView.addMapInializedListener(this);
    address.bind(addressField.textProperty());

}

@Override
public void mapInitialized() {

    geocodingService = new GeocodingService();
    MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();

    mapOptions.center(new LatLong(41.8919300, 12.5113300))
            .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP)
            .overviewMapControl(false)
            .panControl(false)
            .rotateControl(false)
            .scaleControl(false)
            .streetViewControl(false)
            .zoomControl(false)
            .zoom(12);

    map = gmapView.createMap(mapOptions);

}
}
```